# What is the regular expression to extract word which is not preceded by any characters

Tags: regex

For example,

ID is content ID,

need to know the regex to extract the first ID, I tried using `[/b]ID` but is not working

Comment: Please learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Comment: How is this related to java and selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us a lot to go on, but here is an extremely general example:

```
(ID.+)
```

which matches ID and everything after, be it ID:, ID "123", or ID: "123". Note that if you have characters after ID, it will capture that too. Update your question and I will update my answer to accomodate it accordingly.

Here is a live example: http://rubular.com/r/enuYP1kze4.